# Spring Security MVC Login/Logout

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

i want to create simple MVC login / logout form.

Authentication don't work. It grants access to all login-password pair, which i passed to form, but I have only 1 user in ***authentication-manager***. Can you help me to configure? Can you provide me nice samples to Spring MVC Security authentication?

Code you can see below.

**Rest controller:**

```
@Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")
@RequestMapping(value = LOGIN_PAGE_URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String login(UserDto userDto, Principal principal) {
    return "login";
}

@Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
@RequestMapping(value = LOGOUT_PAGE_URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String logout(UserDto userDto) {
    return "Success!";
}
```

**Security configuration xml:**

```
<security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled"
        jsr250-annotations="enabled"
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            username-parameter="email"
            password-parameter="password"
            default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" />
    <security:logout
            invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/"
            logout-url="/logout"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <security:csrf/>
</security:http>
```

**JSP with form:**

```
<spring:bind path = "userDto">
<form class="form-signin" role="form" action="/login" method="post">
    <spring:bind path = "userDto.email">
        <input
            type="email"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Email address"
            name="${status.expression}"
            value="${status.value}"
            required autofocus>
    </spring:bind>
    <spring:bind path = "userDto.password">
        <input
            type="password"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Password"
            name="${status.expression}"
            value="${status.value}"
            required>
    </spring:bind>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you creating a controller? Spring Security is handling that fo r you. Why are you making it more complex then needed. Ditch your controller, your userdto and let spring security handle all that.